# Retina display detection

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, retina-display

I have a problem with detection retina display. I've got two proceses that run simultaneously with the same piece of code:

```
CGFloat scale = [[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor];
```

but in first process scale is 2.0 (must be for retina) and in second process scale is 1.0

I've got no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: What "problem"?  Are you saying that each process shows different results, where the correct result should be 2.0? If so give some details of the processes.

Comment: Both processes run on the same mac pro with retina display. And I expect the same result 2.0, The first process is parent process for the second. Are there any restriction of using piece of code I posted? I'm new to osx development.

Comment: Give some details of the processes.

Comment: child process may not have window (but I'm not sure). I tried to run alert dialog from child process. It worked OK!

Comment: I want to know what sort of processes these are.  Normal OSX apps?  command line apps? LSUIElement apps?  Details please!

Comment: It is chromium browser. First process is main process and the second one is npapi flash process. I run it from command line.

Comment: Did you try it with `[[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0] backingScaleFactor]`?

Comment: Just now. Result is the same.

Comment: Maybe connected with this bug? https://codereview.chromium.org/11642052

Comment: 2Sulthan thanks a lot. The problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read the factor just once at startup on the main thread and store it in some sort of settings object.